# como ejecutar funciones en el contructor de una clase js

Tags: javascript

Queria ejecutar una función de la propia clase en el constructor de dicha clase, en esta caso la finalidad era que la clase iba a ser un juego por lo que en el constructor al llamarle se ejecutase una funcion iniciar que modificase lo que fuese. pero al llamar la variable en el constructor me sale que no esta definida.

```
class JuegoSnake {
  constructor() {

    this.scl = 40;
    this.canv.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.canv.height = Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 1);
    iniciar();

  }


  iniciar() {

    console.log("lo que sea");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Debes llamar con `this.`

```js
class JuegoSnake {
  constructor() {

    this.iniciar();
    this.scl = 40;
//modificación respecto al código del OP para hacer que funcione el constructor
    this.canv = {
      width : window.innerWidth,
      height : Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 1)
    }
  }


  iniciar() {
    console.log("lo que sea");
  }
}
new JuegoSnake();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sencillamente haces referencia al método con `this`. Es la forma correcta y elegante de hacerlo.

```js
class Person{
  constructor(nombre, age){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.age = age;
    // Se llama al método con [ this ]
    this.mostrarDatos();
  }
  
  mostrarDatos(){
    console.log(this.nombre + ' Tiene ' + this.age + ' años.');
    document.write(this.nombre + ' Tiene ' + this.age + ' años.');
  }
}

var yo = new Person('Fulanito Perez', 20);
```

Comment: La respuesta de @x-rw ya da esta solución

Comment: solución que arroja un error. Cuando se dan respuestas con código ejecutables, éstos deben estar funcionales.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
class JuegoSnake {
constructor() {

    this.scl = 40;
    this.canv = {};
    this.canv.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.canv.height = Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 1);
        
    this.iniciar = function() {

        console.log("lo que sea");
    }
    this.iniciar();
}

}


var juego = new JuegoSnake();
```

Comment: ¿radica la diferencia en poner "function" antes del nombre de la función?, si fuese asi, porque sucede esto?

Comment: Correcto, debes de declarar tu funcion como funcion.  Tambien puedes usar Arrow functions.

Comment: ¿y si quiero que esa funcion este dentro de la clase JuegoSnake?

Comment: Simplemente la mueves adentro, ya edite mi respuesta.

Comment: De ese modo iniciar deja de ser un método del objeto, que creo que es parte del objetivo del OP

Comment: Ya edite para que la funcion sea parte del objeto.